# Django admin panel. Не работает поиск по идентификатору

Tags: python, django

Django 3.1
**models.py**

```
class Object(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField('Тип объекта', max_length=255)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'type', )
    search_fields = (
        'id',
    )
```

В админ. панели колонка *id* отображается, но поиск по *id* не работает.
Как заставить работать поиск по *id*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить сравнение *exact*. Тогда поиск по идентификатору *id* начинает работать.
**admin.py**

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'type', )
    search_fields = (
        'id__exact',
    )
```